# Input field still accepts digits in Javascript

Tags: validation, input

My code problem is that the input field for user name still accepts digits .

I tried to validate it with match() and (else if) but still not working. 
The execution jumps to the (else) line.

please any help will be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Functions in JS</title>

<script language="Javascript">

function showName() {
    var entered=document.getElementById("name1").value;
    var patt1 =/\[0-9]/g;

    if( entered !==''){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= entered;
    }   
    else if( entered.match(patt1) ){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="please enter a valid value";
    }   
    else{
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="please enter value";
    }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"   title="Only Alphabets"  >
</form>

<input type="submit" onClick="showName();" >
<p><span id="demo"></span></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you want the back-slash in your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `test()` your input against the pattern. From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp):

> The test() method tests for a match in a string.
>
> This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns
>   false.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function showName() {
        var entered = document.getElementById("name1").value;
        var pattern = /[0-9]+$/;

        if(entered == ""){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Please enter a value";
        } else if(pattern.test(entered)){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Please enter a valid value";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=entered;
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my solution I'm only looking for two exceptions: No input and input contains a number. Everything else is allowed. You might need to change it to your needs :)

Comment: No problem :) Please considier accepting  the answer if it fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showName() {
    var entered=document.getElementById("name1").value;
    var patt1 =/[0-9]+$/;

   if(entered.match(patt1) ){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='please enter a valid value '
    }   
    else{
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= entered;
    }
       
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Functions in JS</title>

<script language="Javascript">


</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"   title="Only Alphabets"  >
</form>

<input type="submit" onClick="showName();" >
<p><span id="demo"></span></p>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/j39qy0aXOlfhkCW8upVL?p=preview